# JSDoc access annotation ignored in Eclipse outline view for variable properties

Tags: javascript, eclipse, jsdoc, eclipse-jsdt

I have the following JavaScript code template in Eclipse. I can see all variable and function properties in the Eclipse outline view. But the access annotation `@private`, `@protected` and `@public` is only reflected for teh function properties in the outline view, not for the variable properties.

```
/**
 * 
 * @constructor
 * @namespace net.namespace1.namespace2.ConstructorName
 * 
 */
var net = net || {};
net.namespace1 = net.namespace1 || {};
net.namespace1.namespace2 = net.namespace1.namespace2 || {};
net.namespace1.namespace2.ConstructorName = function() {

  return {

    /** @private */ 
    var1 : false,
    /** @protected */ 
    var2: false,
    /** @public */ 
    var3: false,

    /**
     * @private
     * @memberOf net.namespace1.namespace2.ConstructorName
     */
    func1 : function() {

    },

    /**
     * @protected
     * @memberOf net.namespace1.namespace2.ConstructorName
     */
    func2 : function() {

    },

    /**
     * @public
     * @memberOf net.namespace1.namespace2.ConstructorName
     */
    func3 : function() {

    }
  }
}
```

See the green, red, yellow functions, but the variables all green.

[image: Eclipse JavaScript outline view]

How can I get the variable properties also be reflected according to the access annotation in the Eclipse outline view?

Comment: Why no @memberOf for them?

Comment: Because if you add `@memberOf` to one the members, then Eclipse recognizes all members in the outline view. But you can add it, if you need it.